# Threading and Queuing with Functions

Tags: python, multithreading, lambda, tkinter, queue

I've been having difficulty with multithreading and tkinter. `slxl` is a module I use that works and its functions do not return values (just to make sure there is no confusion.)

Here is code that **has** worked in the past:

```
    #relevant tkinter code
    def create_widgets():

        self.updatebttn = Button(self, text='Auto Update', command=self.spawnthread)
        self.updatebttn.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N)

        self.progressbar = Progressbar(self, orient='horizontal',
                                       length=300, mode='determinate')
        self.progressbar.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.progressbar["maximum"] = (slxl.sizeFinder()) * 1.1


    def spawnthread(self):
        self.updatebttn.config(state="disabled")
        self.thread = ThreadedClient1(self.queue)
        self.thread.start()
        self.periodiccall()

    def periodiccall(self):
        if self.thread.is_alive():
            self.after(100, self.periodiccall)
            self.progressbar.step(500)
        else:
            self.updatebttn.config(state="active")
            self.progressbar.stop()

class ThreadedClient1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        importer = slxl.runImportAndCoordAdder()
        self.queue.put(importer)
```

The thing is, I would like ThreadedClient1 to be able to take the function it's putting into the queue, in this case `slxl.runImportAndCoordAdder()` as an argument, since I use `ThreadedClient` more than once with different functions (I have an identical use of it later on in the program only with a different function) and I don't like having `ThreadedClient1` and `ThreadedClient2`, the only difference being `importer =` different functions.

I did attempt a solution with lambda as such:

```
def spawnthread(self):
    self.updatebttn.config(state="disabled")
    self.thread = ThreadedClient1(self.queue, lambda: slxl.runImportAndCoordAdder())
    self.thread.start()
    self.periodiccall()

#periodic call is the same

class ThreadedClient1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, fcn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.fcn = fcn
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.queue.put(lambda: self.fcn)
```

This did not work, as it ignored the function I'm interested in, budged the progressbar a bit/disabled and enabled the button, then ended.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
 Problem solved. Another arose, though. I'd like to transfer `spawnthread`, `periodiccall`, and `ThreadedClient` to a widget template module I have and generalize them so I can use them easily. I did this:

```
def spawnthread(self, widget):
    widget.config(state="disabled")
    self.thread = ThreadedClient1(self.queue)
    self.thread.start()
    self.periodiccall()
```

Which worked, until I tried to generalize `periodiccall` as well.

```
    #...
        self.periodiccall(widget=widget)

    def periodiccall(self, widget=None):
        if self.thread.is_alive():
            self.after(100, self.periodiccall)
            self.progressbar.step(500)
            #print widget
        else:
            widget.config(state="active")
            self.progressbar.stop()
```

I popped in the `print widget` to see what was going on since I kept getting an attribute error. What appears to be happening is that the first time it runs though the function it knows what "widget" is and then it turns into in the `None` I wanted it to be by calling `self.periodiccall` in the `after` statement. At least, that's what I think is happening. How do I remove this error and make widget a variable in this recursive function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not calling the function when you use it as an argument for `ThreadedClient1`:

```
class ThreadedClient1(threading.Thread):
    # ...
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.queue.put(lambda: self.fcn)
```

It is just a function that returns a reference to the lambda you pass as an argument, NOT the result of the call to `slxl.runImportAndCoordAdder()`. It should be:

```
class ThreadedClient1(threading.Thread):
    # ...
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.queue.put(self.fcn())
```

Or another solution with the reference directly (without lambdas):

```
def spawnthread(self):
    self.updatebttn.config(state="disabled")
    self.thread = ThreadedClient1(self.queue, slxl.runImportAndCoordAdder)
    self.thread.start()
    self.periodiccall()

class ThreadedClient1(threading.Thread):
    # ...
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        self.queue.put(self.fcn())
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I needed. I'm using lambdas because I'd like to be able to dump spawnthread, periodicall, and threadedclient into my widget template module for cleanliness of code.

Comment: I do have a follow up question; I added it to the original question.